# Read encrypted emails with IMAP

Tags: php, email, encryption, imap

I'm reading a mail box using IMAP functions in PHP.

Regular emails are opened properly and all information is parsed as it should.

However, encrypted emails just return a really long string, even though the same email is readable in the web client (Roundcube) without any problems.

How can I read these encrypted emails? Is there any flag or function I should be using instead of the `imap_fetchbody()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they /encrypted/?  Or just Base64 or Quoted Printable /encoded/?  What is the Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding headers of these messages.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Content-type is set to: `multipart/alternative` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is set to `base64`. Does this mean that I just have to use `base64_decode()` function?

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to be working. If nothing else is necessary to do to read the emails, please move your comment into a reply and I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably quoted printable or base64 encoded. Check the content transfer encoding header, and you should be able to decode them with appropriate functions.